# Python thread - run every X minutes unless last thread is still running

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is for a 3.x python program. One thread is created for a web server - no problems there.

There is another function running in a thread that I would like to run every X seconds unless the prior thread is still running in which case we can skip this iteration. I'm not looking for a break of X seconds between the end of the prior run and the start of a new one.

Desired behavior:

X = 180 seconds (3 minutes)

```
8:00 am - Code begins
8:01 am - Code completes
8:03 am - Code begins
8:07 am - Code completes (we skipped the 8:06 am run)
8:09 am - Code begins
```

The following code runs the function (main) every X seconds, but doesn't check to see if there is already a prior thread running.

```py
def sync():
    t_sync = threading.Timer(syncInterval, sync)
    t_sync.daemon = False
    t_sync.start()

    main()
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

---

Thanks to PygoNode's idea about is_alive() I was able to get the following working. This probably isn't the most elegant way to do this, but it works.

```
def sync():

    t_sync = threading.Thread(target=main)
    t_sync.daemon = False
    t_sync.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep (syncInterval)

        if t_sync.is_alive():
            logger.warning ('Sync: Prior thread still running. Do not kick off another sync.')
        else:
            t_sync = threading.Thread(target=main)
            t_sync.daemon = False
            t_sync.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

threading.Timer has a [is_alive()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) method. You could refactor your `sync()` method to return the thread after starting, and then pass that reference to your next `sync()` call check if the existing is still alive/running.